# The corret session declaration

Tags: php, session

I am just confused with the session in the login configuration.

For example:

```
        if($ensure_credentials) {
        $_SESSION['status'] = 'authorized';
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username; /* save the users username to session */
        header("location: index.php");
    } else return "Please enter a correct username and password";
```

In there it is declared if the login success so that the session status is authorized. But why in the index page it is declared like this:

```
        session_start();
    if($_SESSION['status'] !='authorized') header("location: login.php");
```

Which it means that if the session status is authorized than it will be directed to login page.

I have to ask this question because it always direct me back to login page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anytime you are going to write to a PHP session or read from it you need to make sure a session is started. To do this you can use the following code:

```
if( !isset( $_SESSION ) ){
    session_start();
}
```

To find out what your session currently holds you can do a:

```
print_r( $_SESSION );
```

This will tell you what is currently stored within your active session.

Then you do:

```
if( $ensure_credentials) {
    $_SESSION['status'] = 'authorized';
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;   
    header("location: index.php");
}

if( $_SESSION['status'] !== 'authorized' ){
    header("location: login.php");
}
```